# Visual Studio 2010 text turns blue and red at seemingly random times

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Many times a day, on a new work computer, Visual Studio's code window turns red and blue all of a sudden! The problem only goes away if I restart that instance of Visual Studio or re-apply the fonts & colors settings, closing and opening a file/tab doesn't help.

Only the currently visible file gets the glitch at first when it happens, other open tabs generally retain their proper colors until I reopen them or I open new files - which are then shown with the glitched colors. Sometimes certain types of text in other open files turns blue though, like a virus spreading ;)

[image: screen shot of the problem]

I'm guessing there's a plugin or a missing hotfix or glitchy graphics driver but I haven't figured out what the problem is yet and it's driving me nuts.

I've had this problem once before but don't recall how I fixed it, it's been a while since then and I have many similar installations since that's not showing this issue.

There's also a [Microsoft Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/683042/font-colors-turn-into-blue-red) on it that is closed with status "cannot reproduce" - and it's easy for me to reproduce by simply launching IE9. Sometimes, however, the problem appears without me launching IE.

*Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on Windows 7 SP1, ReSharper 6.1 and Reflector 7.5.4.20. I've disabled hardware acceleration in VS with no difference, it's an Nvidia Geforce 210 with a dual screen setup with primary screen on the right. Also, the markup shown is not written by me and contains no sensitive information*

Comment: Almost like somethings playing with your colour schemes

Comment: Yeah, though a difference is the glitch usually only apply to the currently visible tab... the other opened tabs retains their proper colors, until I re-open them, or open a new file - which then gets the glitch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it actually helped to update Nvidias graphics driver, even though it was just a few months old and for quite an old and trusted graphics card. Oh well - now I'm happy that the problem is gone, and upset that it was so easy.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a small hiccup with the dark theme in Visual Studio. It happened to me when I did a system resume with the VS project still open.  The solution to this is just restarting Visual Studio. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Found this be searching for an answer to the same issue.

They way I fix it is to open Tools -> Options and then click on Environment -> Fonts & Colors to reset the coloring for the current buffer.

It appears to be VS is not recoloring the current buffer after locking the screen for at least 4 mins.  I believe this to be a bug in the themes handling in VS, but I this is really the only place I could find this mentioned.

Just installed SP1 for VS 2010 hoping that it will help, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with vs2013...
This solved the issue..http://madskristensen.net/post/visual-studio-update-2-and-web-essentials

Comment: Please try to give this type of answers in comments